# Zuul proxy with ribbon + listOfServers and logging requirement

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

Hi I have configured Zuul (spring-cloud-netflix) to work with ribbon.

I was able to see  which request is coming to zuul and what requests is being sent to related endpoint in the logs before adding the ribbon to it.

At some point I have added ribbon & load balancing feature.

Now I can not see outgoing req(from zuul to real endpoint) request in the logs. Things are working fine . There is no error . But I need to know/log  incomingReq->outgoingReq information inside the Zuul proxy.  I mean I need the route path information (especially with ip information) .

Is there any way to see/get this information ? I want to log it in a filter if  possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it something like that ..
Hope it helps somebody else too.

```
import com.netflix.client.IResponse;
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.URI;

@Component
public class PostFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    Logger auditLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("auditLogger");

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        URI ribbonResponseURI = ((IResponse) ctx.get("ribbonResponse")).getRequestedURI();
        AuditBean auditBean = (AuditBean) RequestContext.getCurrentContext().get("auditBean");
        auditBean.setIncomingURI(ctx.getRequest().getRequestURL().toString());
        auditBean.setOutgoingURI(ribbonResponseURI.toString());
        auditLogger.info("{}", auditBean.toJson());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this AuditBean class? Where do I import it from?

Comment: its a simple pojo which helps to identify the incoming outgoing urls , you can create your own.